# Why we call memory created using "new" keyword "dynamic memory" since it is also a fixed memory

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, heap-memory, new-operator

Array created this way `int a[5]` contains 5 integer memory blocks and memory can't be changed at runtime.
Array created this way  `int *ptr=new int[5]` also contains 5 integer blocks and in this case too memory cant be increased and decreased at runtime, so, from which perspective it is called dynamic memory.

Comment: It doesn't _resize_ dynamically.  It is _allocated_ dynamically.  What you describe ("can't be increased and decreased") is a property of _arrays_, not the memory the arrays reside in.

Comment: Also. in `new int[5]` - `5` doesn't need to be known at compile time. It can, also, be read, in runtime: `int a; std::cin >> a; int* ptr = new int[a];`. You can't do the same with `int a[5]`;.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colloquial term "dynamic memory" comes from the language defined term "dynamic storage duration". See [Storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) :

> *dynamic storage duration*. The storage for the object is allocated and deallocated per request by using dynamic memory allocation functions. See new-expression for details on initialization of objects with this storage duration.

Objects created with `new` or `new[]` and destroyed with `delete` or `delete[]` have dynamic storage duration.

It is dynamic because the lifetime starts and ends whenever the developper wants it to. Every other storage durations have strict rules about when life time starts and when it ends. It has nothing to do sizes of arrays or resizing arrays. Non-array objects can have dynamic storage duration too.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following case

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int size;
    std::cin>>size;
    int array1[size]; //compile error, the size of static array must be known at compile time
    int* parr=new int[size]; //ok, size of an dynamic array can be unveiled on runtime.
    ....
    ....
}
```

So the dynamic term refers to the fact that user can decide the size of the array whenever he/she wants to.

Comment: `new int;` is also dynamic memory, even though there's no size involved.